# Probability of the sum of a discrete and continuous random variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X \sim Geometric(\frac{1}{2})$ and $Y \sim Exponential(1)$, Let $Z = X + Y$. Find $P(X+Y \le 3.5)$. We can assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

The hint I received was to consider using the Law of Total Probability, setting $F_Z(Z) = P(Z\le z) = P(X + Y = Z)$, I then used the LTP and independence to get $ \displaystyle \sum_X{P(X + Y \le Z \mid X= x)P(X=x)} = \sum_X{P(Y \le Z - X)P(X=x)} = \sum_X{F_Y(z -x)f_X(x)}$.

Taking the derivative with respect to z I can get $ \displaystyle\sum_X{f_Y(z -x)f_X(x)}$, but I'm not sure if it's needed or useful.

I am completely lost on what I need to do to get the final answer as I can only find examples for two discrete or continuous random variables. The answer is supposed to be a numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Condition on $X$ to get $$P(X+Y\leq 3.5)$$$$=EP(Y \leq 3.5-X)$$ $$=P(X=0, Y\leq 3.5)$$ $$+P(X=1, Y \leq 2.5)$$ $$+P(X=2, Y \leq 1.5)$$ $$+P(X=3)P(Y \leq 0.5),$$ Now use independence to finish the computation.